# Allow Teams users to post on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, stack-overflow-for-teams

It [came to my attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310903/284336) this morning that Teams users with no Stack Overflow reputation can not post questions on Meta Stack Overflow.

Since MSO is the preferred location for questions about Teams along with bug reports and feature requests, it seems reasonable that there should be a way to allow them posting permission on MSO.

Comment: Is there even a reason 5 rep is required to post on Meta? What problem is being solved with this? Surely anyone who cant post on meta would just post on the main site instead

Comment: @Tas would you really want Meta to become flooded by spam and "omg y my computer no work???" posts?

Comment: @Tas There are reasons for it. And in specific cases, they're waived, for example, users with less than 5 rep can post a question if they link to a main site post they wrote (so that they can get help with improving it). But many new users don't necessarily understand what meta is, so the network has a policy of limiting access in an extremely minor way.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps we should consider a separate location for Teams support since Meta was designed as a go-to place to discuss Q&A, specifically, not "all Stack Overflow products". *Especially* with, y'know, the culture of Meta and everything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with the latest build, an un-suspended Stack Overflow user who is an active member of a Team can post to Meta Stack Overflow even if they have < 5 reputation.

Comment: How is "active" determined in this context?

Comment: The Team is still live, the user has joined, and the Team admin hasn’t deactivated them.  Basically defunct Teams, deactivated users, or unconfirmed Team members still can’t post to prevent abuse.  We may raise the bar if we find people abuse being able to post on meta.

Answer (score 7):

As I understand it, the 5 rep required to post on Meta is to discourage spammers and people who have no idea about what Meta is or what should (and should not) be posted there. It keeps Meta relatively clean of "omg why my computer no work???" and "High quality herbal supplements call...." posts that are common on the main site.

You are right, this doesn't make sense with respect to many Teams users. Perhaps we could have a rule whereby someone who has contributed meaningfully to Teams automatically gets Meta privileges. I might propose two Teams posts, or possibly even just one. Teams administrators might also be able to "vouch" for their users (e.g. "I know this guy, and I've told him what Meta is for, etc. etc.") and give them Meta privileges from the get-go.

If the user in question is a teams *administrator*, it's a little different. If someone *wants* to pay SO for the privilege of getting downvoted and flagged on Meta, then I can't say much in objection to that. Unless, of course, they are posting ads for dietary supplements, in which case it would be entirely appropriate to nuke their account from high orbit, or at least make them pay for a proper *ad*.

Comment: Why anything at all? Being on a Team requires paying for access. Surely spammers aren't going to go through that just to get access to meta?  If the Teams Team is recommending MSO for support and bugs and features, I don't see why any barriers should exist.

Comment: @Catija I've known plenty of co-workers who had little idea how to use the systems we were expected to use. Just because someone can get a job with an organization that uses Teams doesn't mean that they know how Meta works. In cases where it is clear they *do* and can be trusted, the Team administrator can "vouch" for them as I mentioned above, giving them immediate access to Meta. If the Team administrator refuses, they can just get two proposed edits accepted on the main site (+2 each, for a final rep of 5), and we all know we could always use more of that, and it's good training anyway.

Comment: @Catija i mean, it no longer requires paying for access, so i guess that argument is dead

Comment: @KevinB is MSO experiencing an influx of spammers? The argument isn't completely dead until it's shown that opening this caveat leads to spam.

Comment: i mean... what would qualify as an influx

Comment: "If someone _wants_ to pay SO for the privilege of getting downvoted and flagged on Meta" teams are now free...

Comment: Just curious, was "High quality herbal supplements call...." on an audit or something?  It seems like a pretty weird abstract spam example.

Comment: @Anonymous it's a really common form of spam. [7025](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=Herbal+supplements&feedback=true+positive) posts have been spammed with that.