# After the split between Stack Overflow for Teams and the main Stack Overflow site, can Teams users still participate on Meta without 5 reputation?

Tags: support, meta, stack-overflow-for-teams, privileges

[Since June 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369173/2157772), it's been possible for users who are a member of a Stack Overflow for Teams site to freely participate here on Meta Stack Overflow even if they don't have the [participate in meta](/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege on the main public Stack Overflow site.

However, given the recent changes that completely de-linked Teams profiles from main public Q&A profiles, I'm not certain whether this is still the case. As far as I'm aware, given that, I don't think this meta site can correctly query anymore whether a user is a member of a Team to check if a user can freely post questions and answers here if they don't have the required reputation on the main public site.

Am I correct here? Is it still true that users can participate here if they're members of a Team even if they don't have the required Stack Overflow reputation, or has this changed since the delinking? If it's no longer possible, was it considered and deemed intentional, and if not, can it please be fixed (or the design changed so the behavior matches with the design)?

Comment: This *should not* be allowed. That it worked before was a bug, not a feature. Meta Stack Overflow is a support and discussion site for *public Stack Overflow*. It is not the support site for Teams (although we do allow certain Q&A about Teams here). The company handles support for Teams users themselves.

Comment: @CodyGray Technically speaking, it wasn't a bug, but a feature request that you disagree with but was implemented anyway, as the first link says.

Comment: That said, given that anyone can create a Team now without having to pony up money, circumstances have definitely changed since the 2018 request. I'm personally neutral as to whether the design should be changed to have it be removed or to have additional requirements added (such as it only being allowed for members of paid Teams), but the intended design today is for it to stay.

Comment: I can confirm that you cannot post a question here on meta if you belong to an active Team; I can't post on meta with my work account, I get told I need 5 reputation.

Comment: @Larnu a gentle nudge to post your comment as a proper answer :)